# Averaging values in List contained in Map

Tags: scala

Here is code I wrote to average coordinate values contained within the values of a Map :

```
 val averaged = Map((2,10) -> List((2.0,11.0), (5.0,8.0)))
                                                  //> averaged  : scala.collection.immutable.Map[(Int, Int),List[(Double, Double)
                                                  //| ]] = Map((2,10) -> List((2.0,11.0), (5.0,8.0)))
 averaged.mapValues(m => {


    val s1 = m.map(m => m._1).sum
    val s2 = m.map(m => m._2).sum

  (s1 / m.size , s2 / m.size)
 })                                               //> res0: scala.collection.immutable.Map[(Int, Int),(Double, Double)] = Map((2,
                                                  //| 10) -> (3.5,9.5))
```

This code works as expected but the `mapValues` function requires number of passes equals to length of the List. Is there a more idiomatic method of achieving same using Scala ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, you are asking if it is possible to avoid the traversal of `m` on each *access*.  The `mapValues` method returns a view of a Map, meaning that there will be repeated work on access.  To avoid that, just use `map` instead:

```
val averaged = Map((2, 10) -> List((2.0, 11.0), (5.0, 8.0)))
val result = averaged.map { 
  case (key, m) =>
    val (s1, s2) = m.unzip
    (s1.sum / m.size, s2.sum / m.size)
}
println(result)
// Map((2,10) -> (3.5,9.5))
```

Using `unzip` additionally means that the code won't traverse `m` more than once.

Comment: Works for me.  I just updated with the full code; maybe you're missing something.

Comment: will unzip not be called multiple times as it is contained within the mapValues function or is because (s1,s2) is a val that unzip will be called once ?